# unique random number generation using threads

Tags: c++, random, pthreads

I have a program which use pthreads. In each thread a random number is generated using the rand() (stdlib.h) function. But it seems like every thread is generating the same random number. What is the reason for that??.. Am I doing something wrong??.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` is [***pseudo-random***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and not guaranteed to be thread-safe, regardless, you need to *seed* `rand()`:

```
std::srand(std::time(0)); // use current time as seed for random generator
```

See [**`std::rand()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/) for more details.

A sample program may look like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex output_mutex;

void print_n_randoms(unsigned thread_id, unsigned n)
{
    while (n--)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(output_mutex);
        std::cout << "Thread " << thread_id << ": " << std::rand() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    boost::thread_group threads;
    for (unsigned thread_id = 1; thread_id <= 10; ++thread_id)
    {
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(print_n_randoms, thread_id, 100));
    }
    threads.join_all();
}
```

Note how the pseudo-random number generator is seeded with the time only once (and not *per* thread).

Comment: A random seed is just a number used to initialize a pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: @Zeus Just like you get different forms and kinds of plants from different seeds, you get different sets of numbers from different random generator seeds.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Thanks. That is a great example. You cleared it very well.

Comment: Many C standard functions are not thread safe. But there are thread safe versions of them available. Fortunately rand has also a thread safe version - `rand_r`. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r for details. In Visual C++ there is `rand_s`.

Comment: @lego: That is a useful point, particularly if *repeatable* pseudo-random number generation is required for testing (and `rand_r()` is available on all target systems)!